# Mails randomly appearing in Outbox in Outlook Client

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email, exchange

One of our customers has a weird issue with their team-mailbox (used by 10-15 Users, shared mailbox, managed in Exchange Online). Some Emails seem to randomly appear in the Outbox (of the team-mailbox) and they **stay**, so someone has to delete them. I haven't figured out a criteria by which those mails seem to appear and I'm at odds end here.

It does seem that mails sent by 2-3 users appear more frequently, so I did the standard-procedure consisting of online-repair, .ost delete, cached-mode on/off, etc. but to no avail. Those mails are also not recently sent, some of them are even from last year.

Lastly, I checked in Exchange Online if they have been actually sent or are stuck somewhere. It seems like they all have been sent, but some of them have a delay of about 1-5h before they were sent.

Anyone have any idea what the cause of this issue could be?

Outlook Client Version is 2402(Build 17328.20142)+ where I checked.

Thanks for your Time!

Comment: Do the users actually have permission to send as that mailbox? People can use the wrong From address and get stuck that way. Otherwise you can look into this old issue where the option to change which sent items folder to use causes similar problems - see if they leave the outbox when the associated user manually clicks send/receive?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/email-management/email-remains-in-the-outbox-when-you-use-the-deleg